# JSON analog of GCP Monitoring alert policy in console

Tags: google-cloud-monitoring

I would like GCP to send an alert whenever there is an error  with one of my Cloud Functions that's scheduled to trigger periodically using a scheduler. I went into console and created a policy that looks like this

[policy in console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ghGgr.png) - in short I am monitoring a cloud function error execution count. If error count is above 0 for 1 hour, I should be alerted.

Now my question is two fold.

1. Based on the condition above, I have `any time series violates above 0 for 1 hour`. If I don't close these errors (maybe for 30 days), even if the function is currently executing successfully, I'll still be alerted correct? Is there any way to only alert if `MOST RECENT time series violates above 0 for 1 hour`? If so, how could I write this in JSON format?
2. What is the JSON analog of GCP Monitoring alert policy shown above?

I've pieced together what info I can find in the documentation. This is what I have so far.

```
{
  "conditions": [
    {
       "conditionThreshold": {
       "comparison": "COMPARISON_GT",
       "duration": "3600s",
       "filter": "metric.type=\"cloudfunctions.googleapis.com/function/execution_count" AND 
                  resource.type=\"cloud_function\" AND 
                  function_name=\"function-1\" AND
                  status=\"error\"",
       "thresholdValue": 0,
       "trigger": {
          "count": 1
        }
      }
    }
  ],
}
```

I'm new to StackExchange so if I did not format my question correctly please let me know. Thank you so much for your time and help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Incidents that result from alerting policies will automatically [resolve](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/alerts/incidents-events) once the condition that triggered the incident is no longer true.  You don't need to do anything to "close" the error unless you're just looking to suppress further notifications, which is what "[acknowledge](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/alerts/incidents-events#acknowledging_incidents)" is for.  There's no "most recent" timeseries condition available; you may need to create separate alerting policies per function - and it seems that you're already doing that anyway.
2. Is there a reason you think this JSON is incorrect? I would suggest asking questions based on issues you encounter, rather than asking others to validate your code/work before you have done so yourself.